# Firebase REST api filtering

Tags: api, rest, firebase

Looking at my data in firebase it is structure like so

```
/DebugEvents/0/
/DebugEvents/1/
/DebugEvents/2/
```

under each of those levels are the actual data objects.

I know i can make get requests to /DebugEvents/0/ & /DebugEvents/ to get all, but what if i wanted to filter by `/DebugEvents/0/ & /DebugEvents/2/` but ignore `/DebugEvents/1/` ?

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Not currently, no. You'd need to request those items individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit too @AndrewLee "Not currently, no. You'd need to request those items individually"